# How do I type an alternate type with conditionally existent members?

Tags: typescript, interface, pattern-matching

I have an API that returns this type of result:

```json
{ "success": true, "result": {} } // on success
{ "success": false, "message": "Nope!" } // on failure
```

I tried to create an alternate type like so:

```
interface ResultSuccess<T> {
  success: true;
  result: T;
}
interface ErrorMessage {
  success: false;
  message: string;
}
type Maybe<T> = ResultSuccess<T> | ErrorMessage;

function HandleAPICall(response: Maybe<APIResult>) {
  if (response.success) {
    DoSomething(response.result);
  } else {
    console.log(response.message);
  }
}
```

However on the `console.log` statement i get an error like this:

```
Error   TS2339  (TS) Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Maybe<APIResult>'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'ResultSuccess<number>'.
\maybe.ts   15  Active
```

How do I get the ErrorMessage from the Maybe?

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using? The discriminating union should work here. I see no error here: https://tsplay.dev/qWJoZw

Comment: Ah, yes, did not see this comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enable `strictNullChecks` ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)) in your `tsconfig.json` for discriminated unions on boolean properties to work.